# How to fix this androidx.fragment.app.Fragment android fragment?

Tags: android, fragment

I'm trying to setup in my app that is using androidX.

error: incompatible types: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment cannot be converted to android.app.Fragment  error [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8yYM.png)

Comment: You have to use [getSupportFragmentManager()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentActivity#getSupportFragmentManager()) and not `getFragmentManager()`. For a better understanding you can read [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx).